# Find the latest version of a dataset available in SQL Server on specified dates, using RStudio

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

Each month I run a script in RStudio, on the 9th of the month. I need to manually append the latest DATAyymm sql data set onto the my_data vector, before running the script.

Is there a way I can have the program automatically create this vector? Maybe it could connect to SQL Server and find what the latest available DATAyymm was for the 9th of each month of the year so far?

So if I'm running the script on the 9th of July I would want it to create a vector like this:

```
my_data <- paste0('reference.dbo.', c('DATA20NOV', 'DATA20NOV', 'DATA21FEB', 'DATA21FEB','DATA21MAY','DATA21MAY'))
```

So each of the SQL data sets used represents the data used for each month of the year. In the above case January to June.

Comment: DATA20NOV, DATA21FEB etc are the sql data sets. I import them into the program using sqlquery() function. The values can repeat as i'm using the latest available DATAyymm data set. For example when running January, the latest available data was DATA20NOV. In February the latest available data set was still DATA20NOV. When running March the latest available data set was DATA21FEB. Each of those data sets contain the latest geography data for a particular area, but i didn't think that was relevant information for the purposes of the question.

Comment: I have thought of a solution. I could create a mini data set (single column) in sql server, containing the DATAyymm datasets so far e.g. 6 data sets if using the above example. Then have the program import that mini data set into RStudio and append the latest DATAyymm dataset, then export it back into sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of tables fairly easily with

```r
tblnames <- DBI::dbListTables(con)
tblnames <- unique(grep("^DATA", tblnames, value = TRUE))
tblnames
# [1] "DATA20NOV" "DATA21FEB" "DATA21MAY"
```

With this, we can find the most recent:

```r
gsub("^DATA", "", tblnames)
# [1] "20NOV" "21FEB" "21MAY"
as.Date(paste0(gsub("^DATA", "", tblnames), "01"), format = "%y%b%d")
# [1] "2020-11-01" "2021-02-01" "2021-05-01"

tblnames[order(as.Date(paste0(gsub("^DATA", "", tblnames), "01"), format = "%y%b%d"))]
# [1] "DATA20NOV" "DATA21FEB" "DATA21MAY"
```

This created a vector of the tables ordered (ascending) by its date. With this, you can easily capture the most-recent table created.

To append this month's data, you can use

```r
tblnames <- c(tblnames, toupper(format(Sys.Date(), format = "DATA%y%b")))
```

Comment: That's useful to know. What i really need though is the date each of those data tables went into sql server. For example the DATA21FEB may have been imported 5th March.

Comment: See the code starting with `as.Date(paste0(...))`, it gives you the date (assuming the first day of the month).

Comment: And to be clear, this gives you the date-interpretation of the table name, there is no assurance that that is the date it was inserted into the database. To be certain of that, you'd need to have a column in each table such as `CreatedDateTime DATETIMEOFFSET DEFAULT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`.